# List of entity inside a hibernate entity with @NamedNativeQueries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where i get List of entity in hiberate, But inside the main entity i have another entity list. The entities that i use:

EmpListBean.java

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
 @NamedNativeQuery(
         name = "EmpList",
         //Actual query involves lot of joins
         query = " SELECT ID , NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=:EMPID"    
             ,resultClass = EmpListBean.class
         )
})

@Entity
public class EmpListBean {



@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;    

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String empName;

// This is the list i need to retreive
@ManyToOne
@Column(name="workList")   
private List<WorkListBean> workList;

//Getters & Setters

}
```

WorkListBean.java

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
 @NamedNativeQuery(
         name = "WorkListBeanList",
         query = " SELECT ID , NAME FROM Work_List WHERE EMP_ID=:EMPID"    
             ,resultClass = WorkListBean.class
         )
})

@Entity
public class WorkListBean {



@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;    

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String workName;

//Getters & Setters

}
```

The DAO Layer

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("EmpList");             
query.setParameter("EMPID", myObj.getEmpId());
List<EmpListBean> oEmpListBean = query.list();
```

When executing below DAO layer code I get the "workList" Object as empty , I know this can be achieved by iterating the EmpListBean separately and calling named query for WorkListBean separately , but since the data is huge it takes too much time when doing that way, So wanted to know if there is any way that we could fetch WorkListBean inside EmpList Bean. The two entities used here are only for reference , the actual query i use is complex and could not reveal in this forum and it involves lot of table joins, So kindly let me know how this can be possible in hibernate.

Comment: How can `workList` in `EmpListBean` be `ManyToOne`? It should be `OneToMany`

Comment: Ya. I tried both ways , Even if i put one to many the same issue exists. It still returns null

Comment: Well, you are fetching only `ID, NAME` !

Comment: To illustrate the problem , I am taking only id and name ,but in the real query i fetch a lot of data and also there are few complex joins happening in both the named query

Comment: You should either fetch the entire entity or perform dto projection https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ . What you are trying to do is performing a dto projection on the entity itself and expecting the remaining fields to be filled correctly, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this can be achieved by iterating the EmpListBean separately and calling named query for WorkListBean separately , but since the data is huge it takes too much time when doing that way

I understand you want to merge the two queries to include the data for both entities, then?

Once the association between `EmpListBean` and `WorkListBean` is properly defined, i.e. you have:

```
class EmpListBean {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")
    private List<WorkListBean> workList;
}
```

you should be able to use the following approach:

```
session.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT employee.* FROM EMPLOYEE employee JOIN Work_List wl JOIN ... WHERE wl.EMP_ID=emp.id AND employee.EMP_ID=:EMPID AND ..." )
.addEntity("employee", EmpListBean.class )
.addJoin( "wl", "employee.workList")
.setResultTransformer( Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY )
.list();
```

Not sure if it works for named native queries, though, you'll need to check.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Javalerner you should use @OneTomany and add Eager Loading with fetch="FetchType.EAGER"

and remove the Column annotation

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<WorkListBean> workList;
```

Answer (score 1):

to get whatever `FetchType.LAZY` is, you have to use `JOIN FETCH` in the sentence. When you use `JOIN` you get all whatever  `FetchType.EAGER` is but not whatever `FetchType.LAZY` is

EmpListBean.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="empListBean")
private List<WorkListBean> workList;
```

WorkListBean.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")  
private EmpListBean empListBean;
```

DAO

```
String hql = "SELECT empListBean "
            + "FROM EmpListBean empListBean "
            + "JOIN FETCH empListBean.workList workList "           
            + "WHERE empListBean.id = :EMPID";

        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("EMPID", myObj.getEmpId());
        List<EmpListBean> empListBean = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Abd's response if you're looking for a simple @OneToMany.

Rather than forcing the bean to always eager load, you may want to just incorporate this concept into your NamedNative query using the FETCH JOIN style. Using this approach you can craft queries that are EAGER on an object whose association is otherwise Lazy. In that case, Hibernate will only eagerly fetch via your query and generally be lazy, which is I think what most people want.

Feel free to google around. Here is a well written article that may start you off.

http://www.basilv.com/psd/blog/2008/improving-performance-via-eager-fetching-in-hibernate

Best of luck!